# Two way data binding not working on Angular 6 multiple select

Tags: angular

I am trying to select all options in a multiple select in Angular 6. I have tried a few different approaches, below is what I think should work, but does not.
.html:

```
<button (click)="selectAll()">Select All </button><br>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" multiple size="3">
  <option *ngFor="let opt of possibleOptions">{{opt}}</option>
</select>
```

.ts:

```
selectedOptions = [];
possibleOptions = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

selectAll() {
  this.selectedOptions = this.possibleOptions;
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pc1hj4

Note: I know there are other components that can do multiple select. I am trying to get this working without resorting to a different component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to specify the value of the options:

```
<option *ngFor="let opt of possibleOptions" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! I had it in there in an earlier iteration, but it got pulled out when trying to figure out why it wasn't working.